# Page reload issue in Firefox (window.location.href)

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, onload

I have created a single page website where I show/hide sections. When someone goes to a section (say 'A') of the page and reloads it for the first time then it reloads to the section 'A' but the next time it goes to the home section. For the next reload, it goes to the section 'A' and on the next reload it goes to the home section and so on.

In Chrome everything works fine. I am putting the relevant part of my code below.

```
 window.onload = function() {
   var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
   if (type === "") {
     type = "home";
   }
   $(".section").addClass("d-none");
   $(".section").removeClass("fadeIn animated");
   $("#"+type).removeClass("d-none");
   $(".my_pagination").addClass("selected-"+type);
   $(".pagination-"+type).addClass("active");
};
```

Am I missing something important here?

Comment: If you want the variable to persist between multiple requests, you need to persist it somewhere on the Server side - and there many different approaches to do that... this is not possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what i did is that i replace

```
window.onload = function() {}
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
```